# Using Json returned by PHP in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

My PHP script is returning a JSON object that I am receiving in AJAX call.

```
$arr[0] = $resp;
            $arr[1] = $e;
            return json_encode($arr);
```

Now in my AJAX call , I try to get the value but all I get is `"/"` or `"'"` .

I am doing this in AJAX.

```
dd = JSON.stringify(x.responseText); //this is the response from PHP which is correct I have verified.
alert(dd[0]); //supposed to output $arr[0] but it doesn't
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

[I have seen this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155192/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return)

Comment: @u_mulder the problem is not about alert or console.log or printing, its about getting correct data.

Comment: Console.log and see what you have in dd. `JSON.stringify` btw makes json string from it's argument. Maybe you need `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @u_mulder yes JSON.parse worked :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the JSON.parse solve your problem.

> The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON, optionally
>   transforming the value produced by parsing.

Examples

```
JSON.parse('{}');              // {}
JSON.parse('true');            // true
JSON.parse('"foo"');           // "foo"
JSON.parse('[1, 5, "false"]'); // [1, 5, "false"]
JSON.parse('null');            // null
```

Using the reviver parameter

```
JSON.parse('{"p": 5}', function(k, v) {
  if (k === '') { return v; } // if topmost value, return it,
  return v * 2;               // else return v * 2.
});                           // { p: 10 }

JSON.parse('{"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": {"4": 4, "5": {"6": 6}}}', function(k, v) {
  console.log(k); // log the current property name, the last is "".
  return v;       // return the unchanged property value.
});
```

Ref:

[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

[JSON Example - Object From String](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp)