# JSON not working with CodeIgniter and AJAX

Tags: json, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Good day to all.

Im sorry if I asked this question which stopped me now on my development. I am just a newbie in jquery and json which dont know yet how to manipulate the data. Sorry for this.

As a background, here is my VIEW as I am using a CodeIgniter Framework. This Search button (in yellow) is not the default "Search" of the Boostrap Datatable. Since, as my design, I will search first the last name of the employee then hit the search button. If there are records to be retrieved, then I will add/display it in the datatable.

[image]

So here is my code:

**VIEW:**

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search_empname" id="search_empname" autocomplete="off">                                  

                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btnsearch">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>                                     
                </div>                                  
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="employee_access_dataTables">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="10%">Employee No.</th>
                    <th width="10%">Username</th>
                    <th width="10%">FirstName</th>
                    <th width="10%">MiddleName</th>
                    <th width="10%">LastName</th>                                       
                    <th width="10%">Prim. Role</th>
                    <th width="10%">Sec. Role</th>
                    <th width="10%">Email</th>
                    <th width="10%">Status</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>                         
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function search_employee() {
    $search_empname = trim($this -> security -> xss_clean($this -> input -> get('lastname')));
    $data['empresult'] = $this -> msystems_admin -> search_employee($search_empname);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**AJAX**

```
$('#btnsearch').click(function(){
    var gv_lname = $('#search_empname').val();

    if(gv_lname != ''){
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            cache: false,
            datatype: 'json',
            url:'<?php echo site_url('csystems/search_employee');?>',
            data:'lastname='+gv_lname,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);  
                //I am not sure what to place here          
            }   
        });
    }               
});
```

Can you please emligthen me how to derive the output I desired? Thank you so much in advance.

NOTE: I cannot display the output of JSON even I do an ALERT. :(

UPDATE:
Here's is the Network Tab of the Developer Tool of Chrome. 
[image]

And when I click the URL search_employee, I got nothing preview.
[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
If I changed my CONTROLLER something like this where I will not pass it like JSON.

```
public function search_employee() {
    $search_empname     = trim($this -> security -> xss_clean($this -> input -> get('lastname')));
    $data['empresult']  = $this -> msystems_admin -> search_employee($search_empname);
    //echo json_encode($data);

    foreach ($data['empresult'] as $row){
        $output  = $row -> fname;
        $output .= $row -> mname;
        $output .= $row -> lname;
    }

    echo $output;
```

}

And in my AJAX, I remove the JSON as datatype such as this one below,

```
$('#btnsearch').click(function(){
    var gv_lname = $('#search_empname').val();

    if(gv_lname != ''){
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            cache: false,
            //dataType: 'json',
            url:'<?php echo site_url('csystems/search_employee');?>',
            data:'lastname='+gv_lname,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);  
                //I am not sure what to place here                          
            }   
        });
    }
```

});

Then I got a response as seen from the console logs. Please see the screenshot.
[image]

I am not sure what's wrong with JSON... :(

Comment: For starter you can do url:"<?php echo site_url('csystems/search_employee');?>", and if you are getting the response then $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload(); to reload or refresh the data of datatable

Comment: Hi Praveen, Thank you for your reply. But it does not work as well. :(

Comment: did you got any response from ajax  ?

Comment: Enable logging of ajax requests. Also I recommend using postman app to debug your ajax request it will really help

Comment: I think you better use their provided APIs [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search())

Comment: Hi Praveen, none. When I alert or display it via console, nothing happens. No error in the logs also.

Comment: @levipalmer try to see what your endpoint is returning. If you're with chrome, you have a "Network" tab in developer tools, you should have `search_employee` in the list, click it and then click on preview

Comment: hi @Gwendal, I added a screenshot of the Network tab. I think there's no search_employee being displayed

Comment: @levipalmer you have to open the network tab and then refresh your page, it's not logging anything when tab's not opened

Comment: Open network tab and click on the search button with some value in textbox :)

Comment: Hi @Gwendal, Here it is. I see now the search_employee link. But It has no preview. I attached the screenshot above. Please look at it. Thank you very much for your help with Praveen. Thank you both

Comment: That's weird... 200 OK but no content at all ? Something is happening in your controller. Can you try some echo / var_dump to see if they are displaying ?

Comment: did you load the model with $this->load->model("msystems_admin");
Blank response never seen

Comment: What `console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(data));` gives you ?

Comment: Hi @Praveen, Yes I load the model. Since, I dont load it, I will get an error...

Comment: @levipalmer Okay... Is php error reporting enabled ?

Comment: Hi @Gwendal, yes. When I do a Var_dump, I got a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thanks to @Gwendal and @Praveen for guiding me to this problem. I found the actual error when using JSON.

Using this code in my controller,

```
var_dump(json_encode($data));
var_dump( json_last_error());
```

With this code above, it will return a response in the console log.
And the response of it is this one below:

```
bool(false)
int(5)
```

Now, looking into the PHP manual found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php), this error **int(5)** is related to:

```
0 = JSON_ERROR_NONE
1 = JSON_ERROR_DEPTH
2 = JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH
3 = JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR
4 = JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX
5 = JSON_ERROR_UTF8
```

So right now,  I will be looking at the cause of JSON_ERROR_UTF_8.

Thanks to all of you.

**UPDATE with this error JSON_ERROR_UTF_8**

The reason for this error why it is occurring is that, the JSON format cannot be created from the array returned by the SQL retrieval. It is because of the Resouce ID which is attached to the object. When you do a **print_r** command, you cannot see the resouce id. But if you do a var_dump, then you will notice that no.

Here the screenshot of the two method:

**Using PRINT_R: No Resource ID is seen.**

[image]

**Using VAR_DUMP: Resouce ID is displayed.**
[image]

So from this two screenshots, I have concluded that the returning SQL records have resource id for each record. So, when I encode it using the JSON_ENCODE function, it fails because of that resource id which can't be interpreted.

To solve this issue, I first transpose the resulting SQL result into an associative array then pass that array into the function JSON_ENCODE. With this method, it will give a JSON response.

So in my MODEL, I adjusted this way:

```
public function search($q) {        
    $sql = "SELECT statment here";
    $query = $this -> db -> query($sql);        
    if ($query -> num_rows() > 0) {
        $ctr = 0;
        foreach($query->result() as $row) {
            //make an associative array
            $data[$ctr]['fname'] = $row->fname;
            $data[$ctr]['mname'] = $row->mname;
            $data[$ctr]['lname'] = $row->lname;
            
            $ctr++;

            //list all the other fields here
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then in my CONTROLLER, I can now pass this array to JSON_ENCODE function. So,

```
public function search_employee() {
    $search_empname = trim($this -> security -> xss_clean($this -> input -> get('lastname')));
    $data = $this -> msystems_admin -> search_employee($search_empname);
    echo json_encode($data)     
}
```

As a result, when I run the frontend search, there is now a response via the AJAX call.
[image]

Again, a million thanks to everyone who commented. I got the right direction of debugging this issue. I hope this will help also other newbie like me. Kudos.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
dataType: 'json',   instead of datatype: 'json',
```

T should be capital. 
Hope it works

Comment: Their is no output from the endpoint, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Hi @Gwendal, I updated above. Please see UPDATE 2. As I changed my controller returning only not as JSON but as a string and it works. I got a response in the console log.

Answer (score 0):

Your response header has `Content-Type: text/html`. Try sending the right json header in your response. Add this line to your php before echo:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

See also : [jQuery AJAX Call to PHP Script with JSON Return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155192/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return)