# The usage of `header("Content-type:application/json");`

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I just created an JQuery `ajax` function to retrieve some `json-encoded` data from `PHP`, here's my code :

file name : bank.php

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){

        var datatobesent  = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            data: datatobesent,
            url:'data.php',
            type:'GET'
        })
        .done(function(data){
            console.log(typeof(data));
        });
        return false;
})
```

and in `data.php` I wrote

```
if(isset($_GET)){
    $data = $_GET;
    echo json_encode($data);
    header("Content-type:application/json");
}
```

the question is, when I delete the line of `header("Content-type:application/json");` in `data.php` the `console.log` tell that the type of data returned by `ajax` is `string`.

And when I added `dataType :`json`` inside the `ajax` function in `bank.php` the type changes into `object`

so what is the function of `header("Content-type:application/json");` actually?

Comment: If you are using dataType : Json. then there is no need to use header function, it will give you json result. you just have to parse or stringify

Comment: Side note: headers come **before** body. If your code doesn't crash it's because you've enabled output buffering.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The function `header("Content-type:application/json")` sends the http json header to the browser to inform it what kind of data it expects. You can see all the http headers for each request in your browser (If you are using chrome open developer tools, go to network, adjust the view and reload the page, you will see all requests made by your browser, if you click on any on any of these requests then click on headers you will see the headers of each request).

When you use this function you will notice the http header `Content-Type:application/json` in the response sent from the server. If you don't use it the server will send the default which most likely is `Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8`

As @Monty stated you don't need this function if you added `dataType: 'json'` to your AJAX as Jquery will handle the data even it is sent with text/html header.

See Also: [jQuery AJAX Call to PHP Script with JSON Return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155192/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return)

To read more about headers : [http-headers-for-dummies](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039)

Comment: Or her, Firefox is a momma